# Не работает команда "watch" в sass в консоли

Tags: css, sass, scss

Пытаюсь разобраться с Sass - создал файл style.scss, в командной строке захожу в папку с проектом, ввожу `sass --watch style.scss:style.css`. В результате я получаю -

> Sass is watching for changes. Press Ctrl + C to stop. Encoding::CompatibilityError: incompatible character encodings: IBM866 and UTF-8
>    Use --trace for backtrace.

Помогите, пожалуйста, как с этим разобраться.

Comment: Полный путь к файлу, часом, кириллицы не содержит?

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего путь к файлу содержит кириллицу. Попробуй сделать путь без русских символов, все должно заработать.